# A regex to get any price string

Tags: regex, price

I need to get the price from a string, but no other numbers. There are no restrictions on what the string can say, but it will always have a dollar amount in it.  It's the dollar amount I need to get from the string.

The closest solution I've been able to find is `\d{1,3}[,\\.]?(\\d{1,2})?`

On an example string like, `"2 BED / 2 BATH for $120,000.00, what a deal!!!"`, the regex should only return `$1,000,000`, and no other numbers.  The solution above will return `2`, `2`, and `1,000,000.00`.  An ideal solution should NOT match on any digits that are outside of the dollar amount.  It also needs to include the symbol immediately before the match (to account for the possibility of all currency symbols (USD, GBP, EUR, etc).

So, the price that's matched by the regex should look like: `$120,000.00`, but it could also match on something like `€40,000`

Comment: Unless you enumerate the currency symbols in a set as the leading character, there's no way to do it! How can a bare 2 be distinguished from $2 otherwise?  If you want to be strict about US-compatible locale, you'll end up with something like `[$€](\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d+)(.\d*)?`, except the leading character set must cover every possible currency symbol.  Also this doesn't allow prices like $.42.  It requires $0.42.  If you want the first, I'll let the modification to you. Keep in mind that non-US locales won't use this convention. E.g. European countries switch the roles of `.` and  `,`.

Comment: Should it match `$120.000.00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match all currency symbols before a number with the number itself, you may combine the two expressions:

- [Currency symbol regex](https://regex101.com/r/NVjLIJ/1): `\b(?:[BS]/\.|R(?:D?\$|p))| \b(?:[TN]T|[CJZ])\$|Дин\.|\b(?:Bs|Ft|Gs|K[Mč]|Lek|B[Zr]|k[nr]|[PQLSR]|лв|ден|RM|MT|lei|zł|USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)\b|\$[Ub]|[\p{Sc}ƒ]`
- [Number regex](https://regex101.com/r/WCVQhp/1): `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?!\.?\d)`

Currencies are taken from [*World Currency Symbols*](https://www.xe.com/symbols.php), the 3-letter currency codes used in the pattern are the most commonly used ones, but the comprehensive list can also be compiled using those data.

The answer is

```
(?:\b(?:[BS]/\.|R(?:D?\$|p))|\b(?:[TN]T|[CJZ])\$|Дин\.|\b(?:Bs|Ft|Gs|K[Mč]|Lek|B[Zr]|k[nr]|[PQLSR]|лв|ден|RM|MT|lei|zł|USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)|\$[Ub]|[\p{Sc}ƒ])\s?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?!\.?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVjLIJ/2)

It is created like this: `(?:CUR_SYM_REGEX)\s?NUM_REGEX`, with the lookbehinds in number regex stripped from the pattern since the left-hand context is already defined.

Comment: "EUR 54.200" will not be captured by this regex due to there being 3 numbers after the decimal point however, in europe, this means "fifty-four thousand two-hundred euros" and therefore should be captured as a valid expression.

Comment: @GeorgeSpyrou The answer was based on the examples provided by OP. If there can be more digits in the fractional part, just replace `{1,2}` with `+`. The digit grouping symbols and decimal separators very from culture to culture, you might as well consider `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[,.])(?:\d{1,3}(?:[. \xA0]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d+)?(?![.,]?\d)` [regex to match numbers](https://regex101.com/r/WCVQhp/2).

Answer (score 2):

**This alternative will match any amount without specify the currency**

```
\S+\d[\d,\.]*?\b
```

If you have to specify currency due to misspellings in the input, then you can also use the following regex as an alternative:

```
(?:\p{Sc}|ƒ)[\d,\.]+\\b
```

Note: \p{Sc} can match any Currency Symbol.

The regex '\S+\d[\d,\.]*?\b' tested in a testbench written in Java, to show it handles any amount and currency:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(
            "2 BED / 2 BATH for $120,000.00, what a deal!!!",
            "$1 2 BED / 2 BATH for $120,000.00, what a deal $3",
            "$1.00 2 BED / 2 BATH for $2,000.00, what a deal $300",
            "£40.00 2 BED / 2 BATH for $50,000, what a deal €600.00",
            "₧10 2 BED / 2 BATH for ƒ80.00, what a deal ₨9"
    );

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\d[\\d,\\.]*?\\b");

    for (String input : inputs) {
        System.out.printf("Line to match: '%s'%n", input);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        System.out.println("Extracted price string:");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println("=======================");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line to match: '2 BED / 2 BATH for $120,000.00, what a deal!!!'
Extracted price string:
$120,000.00
=======================
Line to match: '$1 2 BED / 2 BATH for $120,000.00, what a deal $3'
Extracted price string:
$1
$120,000.00
$3
=======================
Line to match: '$1.00 2 BED / 2 BATH for $2,000.00, what a deal $300'
Extracted price string:
$1.00
$2,000.00
$300
=======================
Line to match: '£40.00 2 BED / 2 BATH for $50,000, what a deal €600.00'
Extracted price string:
£40.00
$50,000
€600.00
=======================
Line to match: '₧10 2 BED / 2 BATH for ƒ80.00, what a deal ₨9'
Extracted price string:
₧10
ƒ80.00
₨9
=======================
```

Link to more currency signs:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one

```
[$€]{1}(?P<amount>[\d,\.]+(?>\.\d{2}){0,})\b
```

insert any currency sign into the first group `[$€]` to match them
and try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/4mOj7u/3)